# GPG should fail silently when external card is not inserted, instead of asking over and over

Tags: linux, gnupg, yubikey

I'm running Linux.

I have a Yubikey 4, where my GPG subkeys are stored. On the computer, gpg-agent transparently uses these keys.

The problem is when I don't have my Yubikey inserted. If anything wants to decrypt something (for example, I use `pass` for my passwords, including my email, which is checked on a 2-minute timer with `mbsync`), gpg-agent will dutifully ask me to insert the key. I would much rather it failed silently instead. Is this possible?